# Measure of a section is zero imply other section will be zero?

Tags: measure-theory

How do I see this?

Consider two $\sigma$-finite measure spaces $(X,A,\mu)$ and $(Y,B,\lambda)$. And let $E \in A \otimes B$ such that $\mu(E^y)=0$ $\lambda-$a.e. Than $\lambda(E_x)=0$ $\mu$-a.e.

where $E^y = \{x\in X \mid (x,y) \in E \}$, $E_x = \{y\in Y \mid (x,y) \in E \}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use Fubini and integrate,
$$
0 = \int_Y 0 d\lambda(y) = \int_Y \mu(E^y)d\lambda(y) = \int_Y\int_X 1_{E} d\mu(x)d\lambda(y) $$
$$
= \int_X\int_Y 1_{E} d\lambda(y)d\mu(x) = \int_X \lambda(E_x) d\mu(x)
$$
Since $\lambda(E_x)$ is positive and its integral over $X$ w.r.t $\mu$ is zero, it must be that $\lambda(E_x) = 0$ for $\mu$-a.e. $x$.

Comment: Is the step from single integral to double used Fubini? And is $\mu(E^y)$ a function $f^y$?

Comment: No, remember that the integral of the indicator of a set is the measure of the set, $\int 1_E(x,y) d\mu(x) = \mu(E^y)$. Indeed $y \longmapsto \mu(E^y)$ is a function that we are integrating. It's measurability is typically included in the proof of fubini's theorem.